# How can I identify my unused duplicate Steam keys?

Tags: steam

Let's say I have a list of a thousand Steam keys, mostly for different games. All of those games are already on my Steam account, mostly redeemed from keys on the list. That leaves me with perhaps 200 extra keys. How can I figure out which 200 that is?

Comment: If you're not keeping track of which you've used, how is anyone else supposed to?

Comment: @Frank well that's why OP's asking the question? No need to be so rude (but that's what you do to everyone, so)

Comment: @memescientist There's no rudeness there.  There's a reasonable expectation of organization for a list that grows beyond double digits.  If that organization isn't there, what assistance can we provide?

Comment: We can always give tips on what choices he has.  Which, in this case, are little to none.

Comment: Do you know which keys are for which games?  Or is this just a giant pile of keys that you didn't keep track of at all?

Comment: @Frank yes, I know which keys are for which games, but of two keys for the same game I don't know which one I used.

Answer (score 3):

Short of trying out every key one by one to tell what game it's linked to, no, there's no easy way to identify which key belongs to which game.

Thus, the easiest, simplest way, is to try adding the key to your Steam account.

If you do indeed own the game, Steam will not allow you to redeem game, telling you that you already own the game (including the name of it), and that the key will not be redeemed.

However, there is one caveat.  Because you don't know which keys correspond to which games, if you have a key for a game you'd not like to add to your inventory (because you're a trader, for example), if you don't have the game in your library, it'll get added in right away.

Comment: And this anything what beyond, "Try it and see"?  How is that any different than, "You need to keep track of your used ones yourself"?

Comment: You don't understand.  Again, you're completely unaware of what is going on.  He has a list of keys, but he has no idea which key corresponds to which game.  He wants to know "How can I figure out which key is which." which I provided an answer for.

Comment: You're making some dramatic assumptions, of which point to even more disorganization, and even less help we can provide.  You still haven't actually said anything beyond what I boiled your answer down to.

Comment: And where are these "assumptions"?   The OP has specifically requested how to identify his keys.

Comment: The assumption that he doesn't know which key is for what game.  From the title, it sounds like he knows which key is for which game, but he doesn't know exactly which he used.

Comment: And that's an assumption you're making. You're assuming the OP is making a different point.  Hypocritical much? Calling me out for assuming something by illustrating something you assume OP meant

Comment: You could email support at Steam to find an application for verifying the keys.

Comment: @memescientist All of the games are on my steam account, so trying all the keys is safe, but not helpful. I want to know which keys are unused.

Comment: @Brok3n Steam support is explicitly opposed to any automation or informative handling of keys by users.

Comment: @Sparr Some sites/apps must be able to do it because you see Humble activate keys on behalf of people on their store/bundle pages.

Comment: @Powerlord that's a very special relationship that Valve only grants to a few partners/vendors :(